# Specialize a c++ class member function respect to a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

That's my problem:

I've a class cc and I want to specialize a class member method respect to another template class (with a template argument).
An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <complex>

template<class T>
class cc {
    public:

    void foo() ;

    T v ;
};

template<class T> // OK, generic definition of foo()
void cc<T>::foo() {
    std::cout << v << std::endl ;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ERROR! can not accept the the specialization respect to a 
// complex<TT> with a template argument.
template<class TT> 
void cc< std::complex<TT> >::foo() {
    std::cout << "complex t " << v << std::endl ;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


template<> // OK! specialization respect to a complex<double>
void cc< std::complex<double> >::foo() {
    std::cout << "complex " << v << std::endl ;
}


template<> // OK!
void cc< double >::foo() {
    std::cout << "double: " << v << std::endl ;
}

int main()
{
  cc< std::complex<double> > r ;
  cc<double> r2 ;

  r.foo() ;
  r2.foo() ;
}
```

In c++ complex is a template type, so I want to write a member function that works with every complex< type > where type is any template type.
It is possible?

Comment: template function partial specialization is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can partial specialize the whole class:

```
template<class T>
class cc {
public:

    void foo() { std::cout << v << std::endl ; }

    T v ;
};

template <class T>
class cc<std::complex<T>> {
    public:

    void foo() { std::cout << "complex " << v << std::endl ; }

    std::complex<T> v ;
};
```

or delegating generic method to an "helper" (I show the use of overloads):

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T&v) { std::cout << v << std::endl ;}

template <typename T>
void print(const std::complex<T>& c) { std::cout << "complex " << c << std::endl; }

template<class T>
class cc {
public:
    void foo() { print(v); }

    T v ;
};
```

Comment: Tnx! the delegation in my (real) case is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). The predicate `is_complex` can be made a nested type of the class `cc`, if desired. The `std::enable_if` syntax is a bit better with C++14. Here goes ([online](https://ideone.com/rDxtaT)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <class T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
class cc {
    public:

    template <class TT = T> // To make SFINAE work
    typename std::enable_if<!is_complex<TT>::value>::type foo() {
        std::cout << "default " << v << std::endl ;
    }

    template <class TT = T> // To make SFINAE work
    typename std::enable_if<is_complex<TT>::value>::type foo() {
        std::cout << "complex t " << v << std::endl ;
    }

    T v ;
};

int main()
{
  cc< std::complex<double> > r ;
  cc<double> r2 ;

  r.foo() ;
  r2.foo() ;
}
```

**Delegating**

Inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881654/2378300) by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42), we can implement the `print` function as a templated member function like this ([online](https://ideone.com/eQomjC)):

```
template<class T>
class cc {
    template <typename TT>
    void print(const TT&v) { std::cout << v << std::endl ;}

    template <typename TT>
    void print(const std::complex<TT>& c) { std::cout << "complex " << c << std::endl; }

public:
    void foo() { print(v); }

    T v ;
};
```

Comment: Note that in your SFINAE implementation, we can cheat and call `cc<int>{}.foo<std::complex<double>>()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 True, but there is an easy fix, by adding `and std::is_same<T, TT>::value` to the `enable_if` parameter.